Server-side multi-criteria sorting with php-ldap
Since PHP 8, the ldap_sort() function has been deprecated, so thanks to helphull answer of MarvinM at
What is a replacement for LDAP_sort method which is deprecated, I use request_control:
$request_controls=[['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS, 'value' => ['size' => 750, 'cookie' => $cookie]], ['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_SORTREQUEST, 'value' => [['attr' => 'sn']]]];
$result = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $WhoisBaseDN, $filter, ['sn', 'c', 'o', 'departmentnumber', 'employeeid', 'givenname', 'title', 'ipphone', 'telephonenumber', 'mobile', 'mail'], 0, 0, 0, LDAP_DEREF_NEVER, $request_controls); 

And it works correctly with only a single sort criteria.
According to LDAP documentation, it should be possible to use a secondary sort criterion (such as first name if several people have the same name).
I've tried using an array of arrays like this :
$request_controls=[['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS, 'value' => ['size' => 750, 'cookie' => $cookie]], ['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_SORTREQUEST, 'value' => [['attr' => 'sn'], ['attr' => 'givenname']]]];

documentation
But I get a Php error :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: ldap_parse_result(): Argument #2 ($result) must be of type LDAP\Result, bool


Do you have any error logged from your ldap server ? What happens if your try with 'uid' (or 'samAccountName' if you are on AD) instead of 'givenname' as second criteria ?
